# Use of Arrow Member Selection Operator in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, pointers

I having been revising C++ the past few days and was just reading on the arrow member selection operator.

in C++:

```
MyClass classObject;
MyClass *classPointer = &classObject;

classPointer->someFunction();
```

This is how the arrow member selection operator used to access the function.

But in Objective-C:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[vc someFunction];
```

I am used to writing such code. Why is this code right? Now after revising C++, this does not make sense to me.

Sorry if it is a stupid question.

Would like to understand this concept better.

Comment: You are apparently looking at Objective C code, not C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

The second piece of code you mentioned is indeed Objective-C.

What is actually happening here is that you are sending a message to `vc` to invoke the `someFunction` method.

The Objective-C runtime handles these messages.

The details are outlined in Apple's documentation on the Objective-C runtime if you are interested: [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide: Messaging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

Your first code sniplet is right in a C++ context and the second sniplet is right in an Objective-C context.

Both are different programming language which probably share more things in common than they have differences. At least both are based on standard C. 
Some of the differences are quite significant like the binding process for instance.

What was your question?

If it really is about the arrow operator. That still exists in Obj-C to the extend that it was "inherited" from C. Underneath every object in Obj-C is represented in memory by a C struct (which is similar to C++ objects) and therefore you can access reglular iVars with the arrow operator but no regular methods.

(You could of course tweak it by abusing regular C pointer arithmetic and use a pointer as function call and in the event that you do it right than it should even work fine. But what for?)